# Excel: Auto Assign Staff to a their area of expertise

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to build a table that will have 3 columns and assign staff based on a criteria from one of the columns. Our columns are simply A, B, and C.  In column A, there will be a filing number that will be added manually and column B will be the Area and will be added manually from a drop down list via Data Validation. Column C I would like to have 'auto-populated' from a list of staff that are 'experts' in that area. Each staff is available 100% of the time so there can be times of rotation that will have their name more than once.  Here is an example of those list for visual aid:

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfU8B.png)

So when each area from column B (Area) is selected, Column C will 'random select' from the staff in the table shown in column F, G, and H with their respective areas of expertise. Here is a another visual of the result I would like:

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvwha.png)

Is there a code for column C to get that result? I have tried a number of `=rand` or `=randbetween` and I also used the following formula to create another drop down list to manual select, again through data validation and this works:

=OFFSET(TABLE1!$F$1,1,MATCH($B2,TABLE2!$F$1:$H$1,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET(Settings!$F$1,1,MATCH($B2,Settings!$F$1:$H$1,0)-1,3)),1)

but I want it to be automated to eliminate that step of selecting from a dropdown since this is done in column B as well. Or is this a VBA type of build as this list will grown over time?

Thank you for taking the time to assist and I will be available for any questions.

Comment: I would approach this with the solver, and  use a "skill level" or time or cost to control the total. Or you can set a total of how many times each must be used.

Comment: Please include your attempted formulae to make this on-topic. Also, please can you post markdown sample data instead?

Comment: This is possible with a formula, but it would be greatly simplified if your expert list was two columns, one for name and one for specialty, with multiple entries for each name.  Also, what is your excel version?  It will also be simpler if you have a newer version which has access to functions like FILTER and UNIQUE.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland my apologies for missing this information. I am using Excel 365. Also the table on the right can be converted to show just the names and their specialties.  I do have access to those functions you listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this google sheet.  The formulas should be the same in Excel:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bCVsCxXnG3an1LZSCwVdzlZCSSctxdfy3WHQ7RisOY4/edit#gid=0

If you reformat the specialty list to two columns, with one column for the name and one for the specialty, you can use

```
=index(unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2)), randBetween(1,COUNTA(unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2)))))
```

Reformatted for easier reading:

```
=index(
  unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2)), 
  randBetween(1, COUNTA(unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2))))
)
```

You use FILTER to get the list of matching names.  I wrapped that in UNIQUE just in case there were mistaken multiple entries for the same name and same specialty.

```
unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2))
```

You can pass that to COUNTA to get the count of matching names:

```
COUNTA(unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2)))
```

And use that in RANDBETWEEN to get a random number between 1 and the number of matches:

```
randBetween(1, COUNTA(unique(filter(E:E, F:F=B2))))
```

Then use INDEX to get the nth name out of the list, where the first argument is the unique filtered list and the second argument is the number generated with RANDBETWEEN.

Excel has a LET function which will let you reuse arguments, and may be simpler to read or maintain. This is not in the sheet, since I don't think Google Sheets has that function.

```
=LET(
  list, UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E, F:F=B2)),
  INDEX(list, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(list)))
)
```

LET takes pairs of name/values as arguments, with a final argument that is the output.  Here list is the name and the unique/filter combo is the definition.  Then you can use the name in the output formula

```
INDEX(list, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(list)))
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Chris, the first function formula does the trick with a hiccup though.  In my column b, I have a data validation selection list dropdown for the specialties. So when the user selects one, then the a random name that specializes appears (as the function works).  Here is where the hiccup occurs. The moment I go to the next row (which is a null space), select a specialty from the dropdown, the previous row name changes after giving me the random name. Odd. Am I missing a locking function to not change the previous row?

Comment: RAND and RANDBETWEEN are volatile.  They will recalculate every time data in the sheet changes.  So if you want them to stay put you'll need to either copy and then paste as value OR you can turn off automatic calculations in the sheet, so that it only calculates the new one.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I greatly appreciate the assistance.  I am confirming this solved/answered my questions.

Comment: @ACKoop: hey, I just noticed that the second formula (with LET) was using R1C1 reference style.  I usually used that and forgot to switch to A1 when I wrote that second one.  I wrote the first one in the Google Sheet, which only has A1.  Check that and see if that works for you / you like it better.  LET is handy, but it doesn't really shorten this formula up.  It might make it more readable, plus if you change the list definition you only have to change it in one place, so it might be easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for this update on that function formula.  Tried it as well and it works correctly just as the first one.  My venture now is to lock it to a cell so the next in line doesn't change the previous result.  Trying create a "Auto Assign" table/spreadsheet in a sense that will eventually roll over to access possibly but want to see if it could be done using a small data set.  Again thank you thank you as this portion was confusing me.  Now I am going to turn off the auto calculation and see where that leads me.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the initial mistake.  R1C1 is much easier to use, so I often forget to switch when writing these stack overflow answers.  I'll think about the locking in problem and see if I can think of a solution that doesn't require copy/paste or turning off the autocalculate, both of which could be a real pain.

Comment: No apologies needed as I am grateful for any assistance in my goal. I am going to try to tinker with some of the option to see if any luck comes up with a solution for the locking in but please feel free at anytime to share a strategy as I am still learning and advancing myself in the world of excel as opposed to query writing.